# Calling a new procedure error Undeclared Identifier

Tags: delphi

Hello I am writing a new application and have made a little procedure (UpdateTotals). The application compiles and works well until I call this new procedure. Then I get the Undeclared Tdentifier error. I have written procedures and functions before but have never had this error except when I forget to put the form identifier in front of the procedure.
My code is

```
unit ng1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, 

  ...

  DateUtils, StrUtils;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    InText : TEdit;
    qsum : TQuery;
    
    ...
    
    procedure UpdateTotals;
    procedure InTextKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
      Shift: TShiftState);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure NewshbtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure qbtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure numedExit(Sender: TObject);
    procedure mc1DropDown(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  pcname : string;
  wsum, hsum, totsum, ssum, stotsum:Real;
  wcnt, hcnt, totcnt, sscnt, stotcnt, pcnum :Integer;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.UpdateTotals;
begin
  qsum.Close;
  qsum.SQL.Text:='select sum(amount) from dest1';
  qsum.Open;
  wsum:=qsum.Fields[0].AsFloat;
  wcnt:=qsum.RecordCount;
  qsum.Close;
  qsum.SQL.Text:='select sum(amount) from desty';
  qsum.Open;
  hsum:=qsum.Fields[0].AsFloat;
  hcnt:=qsum.RecordCount;
  totsum:=wsum+hsum;
  totcnt:=wcnt+hcnt;
   case AnsiIndexStr(pcname, ['SHOP','EILEEN-PC','DAVID'] )   of
      0: pcnum := 1;
      1: pcnum := 2;
      2: pcnum := 3;
   end;
  qsum.Close;
  qum.SQL.Text:='select sum(amount) from session';
  qsum.Open;
  ssum:=qsum.Fields[0].AsFloat;
  sscnt:=qsum.RecordCount;
  stotsum:=stotsum+ssum;
  stotcnt:=stotcnt+sscnt;
  zg1.Cells[1,2]:=IntToStr(wcnt);

...

end;
...

end.
```

I call the procedure

```
UpdateTotals;
```

Can anyone help please?

I am sorry the error code I get is

```
[Error] ng1.pas(185): Undeclared identifier: 'UpdateTotals'
[Fatal Error] ngift.dpr(5): Could not compile used unit 'ng1.pas'
```

when I call the procedure from another procedure (below) which is called on form activate

```
procedure fillhead(zgg:TZColorStringGrid);
var
  Rct: TRect;
  res: integer;
begin
  res := zgg.MergeCells.AddRectXY(1, 0, 3, 0);
  res := zgg.MergeCells.AddRectXY(4, 0, 6, 0);
  res := zgg.MergeCells.AddRectXY(7, 0, 9, 0);
  zgg.Cells[1,0]:='Warminster Road';
  zgg.Cells[4,0]:='High Street';
  zgg.Cells[7,0]:='Totals';
  zgg.Cells[1,1]:='Entries:';
  zgg.Cells[4,1]:='Entries:';
  zgg.Cells[7,1]:='Entries:';
  zgg.Cells[2,1]:='Amount:';
  zgg.Cells[5,1]:='Amount:';
  zgg.Cells[8,1]:='Amount:';
  zgg.Cells[3,1]:='Claim:';
  zgg.Cells[6,1]:='Claim:';
  zgg.Cells[9,1]:='Claim:';
  zgg.Cells[0,2]:='Quarter Totals';
  zgg.Cells[0,3]:='This Session';
  UpdateTotals;// The compile time error occurs here
end;
```

Comment: You mean that you get a compile-time error when you add the line `UpdateTolals`? If so, perhaps you aren't in a method of `TForm1`?

Comment: You've not shown us where you're calling `UpdateTotals` from, which is relevant. Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue and the **exact** error message you're seeing.

Comment: You should have a look at the source code line where the error occurs: "Undeclared identifier" means you used an identifier (Variable, name, function name,...) which is not known in the context of the line where the error occurs. It is likely that the complete error message mention which identifier is unknown. So please give the EXACT error message you get and the source code where it occurs.

Comment: I have added code as requested

Comment: Yes, my guess in my first comment was correct. You are attempting to call the method outside the class. You need to learn the difference between regular procedures/functions and [methods](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Methods_(Delphi)). (It's not "right", but likely you get the behaviour you want simply by writing `Form1.UpdateTotals`.)

Answer (score 2):

Your `fillhead` procedure is not a method of an object, while your declaration of `UpdateTotals` is a member of `TForm1`. You're calling `UpdateTotals` inside `fillhead`, which means you need to preface it with the name of the class instance (`Form1`) which contains `UpdateTotals`.

```
procedure fillhead(zgg:TZColorStringGrid);
var
  Rct: TRect;
  res: integer;
begin
  res := zgg.MergeCells.AddRectXY(1, 0, 3, 0);
  res := zgg.MergeCells.AddRectXY(4, 0, 6, 0);
  res := zgg.MergeCells.AddRectXY(7, 0, 9, 0);
  zgg.Cells[1,0]:='Warminster Road';
  zgg.Cells[4,0]:='High Street';
  zgg.Cells[7,0]:='Totals';
  zgg.Cells[1,1]:='Entries:';
  zgg.Cells[4,1]:='Entries:';
  zgg.Cells[7,1]:='Entries:';
  zgg.Cells[2,1]:='Amount:';
  zgg.Cells[5,1]:='Amount:';
  zgg.Cells[8,1]:='Amount:';
  zgg.Cells[3,1]:='Claim:';
  zgg.Cells[6,1]:='Claim:';
  zgg.Cells[9,1]:='Claim:';
  zgg.Cells[0,2]:='Quarter Totals';
  zgg.Cells[0,3]:='This Session';
  Form1.UpdateTotals; 
end;
```

Note that this would hard-code it being called only for `Form1`, so it would be inaccessible from another form with a different name. You should either make `fillhead` a member of `TForm1`, where you don't need to decide which form is calling it, or change `fillhead` to accept another parameter that represents the form instance.

```
procedure fillhead(AForm: TForm1; zgg:TZColorStringGrid);
var
  Rct: TRect;
  res: integer;
begin
  res := zgg.MergeCells.AddRectXY(1, 0, 3, 0);
  res := zgg.MergeCells.AddRectXY(4, 0, 6, 0);
  res := zgg.MergeCells.AddRectXY(7, 0, 9, 0);
  zgg.Cells[1,0]:='Warminster Road';
  zgg.Cells[4,0]:='High Street';
  zgg.Cells[7,0]:='Totals';
  zgg.Cells[1,1]:='Entries:';
  zgg.Cells[4,1]:='Entries:';
  zgg.Cells[7,1]:='Entries:';
  zgg.Cells[2,1]:='Amount:';
  zgg.Cells[5,1]:='Amount:';
  zgg.Cells[8,1]:='Amount:';
  zgg.Cells[3,1]:='Claim:';
  zgg.Cells[6,1]:='Claim:';
  zgg.Cells[9,1]:='Claim:';
  zgg.Cells[0,2]:='Quarter Totals';
  zgg.Cells[0,3]:='This Session';
  AForm.UpdateTotals;
end;
```

My preference would be to make `fillhead` a member of the `TForm1` class itself, and remove the need to pass the stringgrid in at all. This means that you can use the code without worrying in any use of `TForm1`, allowing you to create multiple instances of that form at the same time.

Comment: Thank you both. The first comment about learning the difference between procedures and methods left me puzzled but the clear and helpfu comment above has explaines it wonderfully and I feel I have learnt something very useful. Thank you again